# Is there a CSS selector for the actual text inside an input? (for a "text-indent" alternative)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, electron

I have this need to perform animations using `transform` that will mimic the functionality of `text-indent` in a text input because animating `text-indent` ends up jittery/laggy. Doing this on Electron so anything that'll work in Chrome is good to go.

I've found out about the `::-ms-value` selector but that doesn't seem to do anything on Chrome. Using a wrapper div and moving the whole input is also not an option for me since It's a massive Vue component that's already written and very complicated. Using the wrapper approach would require a painful days-long complete rewrite of the component.

If there's no selector, any alternative to solve my issue would be appreciated. I wouldn't mind doing it via JS too. Animation needs to happen on `focus` and `blur` events of the input.

It's the last step of fixing this laggy horror.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

There is no selector for actual value, however you can use javascript to set an attribute on `input` event and use that attribute as selector:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("input", function(e)
{
  this.setAttribute("value", this.value);
});
```

```css
input:not([value=""])
{
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="test" value="">
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think you understood my question. I don't need to select the input with a specific value. I need to select the visual text part itself so I can do `transform` on it. Thank you for the response though.

Comment: Please provide minimal code so we can see the issue at hand than. How are you planning on using "value" selector in CSS?

Comment: I don't think it needs any minimal code. Simply indent on blur and focus but with hardware accelerated transitions. That's all. Unfortunately I can't share the code of a closed source project. For you to see the whole picture, I have to share the whole component accompanied by all the dependencies.

Comment: Well, your question is about "selector for input value", but if I understand you correctly now, it's about moving around text inside an input... I'm not asking for the code from your project, I'm asking for an example so we can see "jittery/laggy" issue.

Comment: this works perfectly smooth for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/xbcL9ynz/

Comment: It works smoothly only because the DOM is not very populated. Things change a lot when the number of DOM nodes increase and more styles, JS stuff are added. All the non-compositing properties that are animated becomes unbearable. I've tried adding a couple hundred table rows to your fiddle but miraculously it works fine though. Still, it's a good practice not to animate that stuff. Sooner or later you run into lagging issues.

Comment: Well, that's the problem, without actual code that reproduces the issue, how can someone help? We'd have to blindly guess what could possibly work for you and what not, that's just wasting time...

Comment: But it's a well established fact that non-compositing animations are jittery on HTML. So I thought what's the point of proving that again. I just wanted to animate the text inside input using `transform`.

Comment: I don't believe there is a way access text inside input directly with css, however now I'm intrigued to see an example animation for anything that would be not jittery in your case...If you can provide that, perhaps you could apply it to something like this, where input is "faked" style-wise (for Edge): https://jsfiddle.net/37t8wpne/

Comment: Thank you for that. But that's also gonna be jittery since `width` is non-compositing. All animations that aren't hardware accelerated becomes laggy when the DOM becomes complex. Only thing that's gonna work in my case is `transform: translateX()` since It's accelerated;